# Wordpress fallback thumbnail size

Tags: wordpress

I have just imported about 1000 posts from an old wordpress site into a new one. The new theme requires images that are larger than the previous one, and to conform to a certain aspect ratio (4:3).

I have set up a custom image size:

```
add_image_size( 'blog_thumbnail', 640, 480, true);
```

which works, but as most of the images from the previous site were smaller than this, they are not being cropped, which is a problem because they are not all 4:3 (in fact they used about 20 different ratios).

So I've set up a fallback image size which will cover all the images:

```
add_image_size( 'blog_thumbnail_mini', 300, 225, true);
```

But I can't think of a way of setting this as a fallback other than including both and hiding the fallback with CSS if the larger is present, which seems like a sub-optimal solution.

I'm using pretty standard code to embed the image:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id($post['ID']), 'blog_thumbnail' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ which will regenerate your new thumbnail size `640, 480` from the original full size image.

But how well that works depends on if the full size images still exist - you can usually spot them in /uploads/ as an image with the title and no sizing, or in the media library - and if full size images are of sufficient size and quality to allow resizing.

**Edit 10/20/16**

You can try checking the minimum width of the current thumbnail and either using that or falling back to another thumbnail size:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
    $imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'current_blog_thumbnail' );
    $imgwidth = $imgdata[1];                 
    $minimum_width = 300; //change this minimum width to what you need
    if ( ($imgwidth < $minimum_width ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail('current_blog_thumbnail');
    } else { 
        the_post_thumbnail('fallback_blog_thumbnail');
        }
}
```

Comment: Regenerate thumbnails won't work, because I know many (most even) are not large enough.